# Apply join to whole mySQL table

Tags: mysql, join

I have two mySQL tables in my database

**Training:**

```
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+-...-+------------+
| Training_ID | 09-06-2012 | 16-06-2012 | 23-06-2012 | ... | 28-12-2013 |
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+-...-+------------+
|     1       |    123     |    924     |   367      |     |   679      |
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+-...-+------------+
|     2       |    243     |    626     |   381      |     |   771      |
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+-...-+------------+
|     3       |    766     |    826     |   956      |     |   725      |
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+-...-+------------+
```

**Users:**

```
+---------+----------+
| User_ID | Name     |
+---------+----------+
|   123   | Fred     | 
+---------+----------+
|   924   | James    | 
+---------+----------+ 
|   367   | Tim      | 
+---------+----------+
|   766   | Mark     | 
+---------+----------+
```

**What I want to show is:**

```
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+-...-+------------+
| Training_ID | 09-06-2012 | 16-06-2012  | 23-06-2012 | ... | 28-12-2013 |
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+-...-+------------+
|     1       | 123 - Fred | 924 - James | 367 - Tim  |     | 679 - Ben  |
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+-...-+------------+
|     2       | 243 - Sarah| 626 - Smith | 381 - Exam |     | 771 - John |
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+-...-+------------+
|     3       | 766 - Mark | 826 - Jone  | 956 - Case |     | 725 - Brett|
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+-...-+------------+
```

**Note:** there are actually 70 columns (all the same format as the above).

I tried using joins - but I cant do one for each column.

Is there a way to apply a join to the whole table?

Comment: "Is there a way to apply a join to the whole table?" --- just generate query by your programming language

Comment: Your Training table has dates for column names?!  Could you tell us more about your schema?

Comment: @SetFreeByTruth - yes - I inherited this design - basically there are alot more rows aswell. Basically it is the equivalent of an online spreadsheet, with lots of columns and rows. So the database was setup to reflect that. The columns and rows are always displayed to the user in full - so it was working well, until now...

Comment: Wow :).  Can you show us an example of another query you've written against that table so we can understand how you specify the field names?  That design seems quite unwieldy; I feel bad for you :P.

Comment: I would **SERIOUSLY** think about re-engineering it. So you have to alter the table each time a new date needs to be added.

Comment: Thanks everyone - I think I'll just redo the whole section, make my life easier moving forward. Any ideas on how best to re-write this schema to be most effective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a terrible design and any query you're going to perform to produce your desired format will also look equally as horrid, but it isn't impossible:

What you can do is make a single Cartesian-join of the `training` and `users` table, then `GROUP BY` the `training_id`, and make a bunch of conditional aggregations which will put everything on one row per `training_id`:

```
SELECT
    a.training_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN a.`09-06-2012` = b.user_id THEN CONCAT(a.`09-06-2012`, ' - ', b.name) END) AS `09-06-2012`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN a.`16-06-2012` = b.user_id THEN CONCAT(a.`16-06-2012`, ' - ', b.name) END) AS `16-06-2012`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN a.`23-06-2012` = b.user_id THEN CONCAT(a.`23-06-2012`, ' - ', b.name) END) AS `23-06-2012`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN a.`28-12-2013` = b.user_id THEN CONCAT(a.`28-12-2013`, ' - ', b.name) END) AS `28-12-2013`
FROM training a
CROSS JOIN users b
GROUP BY a.training_id
```

You'll need as many `MAX(CASE WHEN`... columns in your `SELECT` clause as there are columns in your table.

While this may also look ugly, it is much more efficient than joining the `users` table 70 different times for each column.

---

### [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf2d3/1/0) with just four columns